# Somar entrada e saída e subtrair

Tags: jquery, html, tabela-html

Tenho este [código](http://jsfiddle.net/1qufobt3/1/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $entrada = 0,
        $saida = 0,
        $total = 0;
    $.each($("td[name='entrada']"), function() {
        $entrada += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $.each($("td[name='saida']"), function() {
        $saida += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $total = $entrada - $saida;
    $("body").append("TOTAL ENTRADA = R$ " + $entrada + "<br />")
             .append("TOTAL SAIDA = R$ " + $saida + "<br />")
             .append("TOTAL GERAL = R$ " + $total + "<br />");
});
```

```html
<body>
    <table width="" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ENTRADA</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="198" border="1" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">PRODUTO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>SAIDA</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="196" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">DESCRICAO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <td>SAIDA</td>
        <td name="saida">50,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Preciso das somas dos valores totais fora do *javascript* tipo dentro de uma tabela ou id div

Sei que isso é para quem manja de *javascript* alguém poderia me ajudar

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida. Você quer somar sem usar javascript?

Comment: Mas o seu código já não está fazendo isso corretamente? o_o

Comment: Também não percebi o que está a faltar... podes explicar melhor o que não sabes fazer?

Comment: Eu quero os totais dentro de uma tabela como nao manjo muito de javascript.

Comment: ta resolvido esse assunto ?

Answer (score 1):

Se é o que entendi você quer colocar tabela com javascript, se é isso então é só adiciona o javascript conforme abaixo

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $entrada = 0,
    $saida = 0,
    $total = 0;
$.each($("td[name='entrada']"), function() {
    $entrada += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
});
$.each($("td[name='saida']"), function() {
    $saida += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
});
$total = $entrada - $saida;
var $table = $('<table>').attr('border',1);
$table.append('<tr><td>TOTAL ENTRADA</td><td>'+ $entrada +'</td></tr>');
$table.append('<tr><td>TOTAL SAIDA</td><td>'+ $saida +'</td></tr>');
$table.append('<tr><td>TOTAL GERAL</td><td>'+ $total +'</td></tr>');
$("body").append($table);
$("body").append("TOTAL ENTRADA = R$ " + $entrada + "<br />")
         .append("TOTAL SAIDA = R$ " + $saida + "<br />")
         .append("TOTAL GERAL = R$ " + $total + "<br />");
});
```