# Valor total fora do código

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código abaixo, que está fazendo soma como eu quero, porém gostaria que ele gerasse valores totais, tipo:

> TOTAL ENTRADA = R$ 200 
>   TOTAL SAIDA = R$ 50 
>   TOTAL GERAL = R$ 150

Queria que fosse fora do código do `javascript`, tipo entre o corpo. Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão? Segue abaixo o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $entrada = 0,
        $saida = 0,
        $total = 0;
    $.each($("td[name='entrada']"), function() {
        $entrada += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $.each($("td[name='saida']"), function() {
        $saida += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $total = $entrada - $saida;
    $("body").append("TOTAL ENTRADA = R$ " + $entrada + "<br />")
             .append("TOTAL SAIDA = R$ " + $saida + "<br />")
             .append("TOTAL GERAL = R$ " + $total + "<br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table width="" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ENTRADA</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="198" border="1" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">PRODUTO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>SAIDA</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="196" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">DESCRICAO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <td>SAIDA</td>
        <td name="saida">50,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1qufobt3/1/

Comment: Queria os valores fora do código javascript tipo dentro de uma div

Comment: Por gentileza, Hemerson, dê-nos mais detalhes do seu problema. O que você quer especificamente e um exemplo do resultado desejado vai ajudar bastante.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Somar entrada e saída e subtrair](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61317/somar-entrada-e-sa%c3%adda-e-subtrair)